# QSqlQuery inserting QByteArray as string into PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qsqlquery, qbytearray

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4.5 table with a column with basic character data type, i.e. created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL);
```

I then insert data using QSqlQuery, using a bound QByteArray:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO films VALUES (1, ?)");
const QByteArray film("Avatar");
query.addBindValue(film);
query.exec();
```

On Ubuntu 15.10, the film name goes into the table as bytes:

```
\x417661746172
```

On Windows, it goes in as characters.

Without explicitly casting the QByteArray to QString, is there any way to tell QSqlQuery or PostgreSQL to treat the data as a string, so it works on Ubuntu as it does on Windows?

Comment: The basic question - is there any reason to use `QByteArray` instead of `QString`? In the cited code I can't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `QByteArray` has no information about the encoding of the string it contains (or even that the sequence of bytes it contains can be interpreted as an encoded string).

If it happens to contain an UTF-8 encoded string, you might either

- Bind it as a string with `QString::fromUtf8(film.constData())` instead of just `film`
- let the Qt driver pass it as `bytea`, but have PostgreSQL convert it to text  through the INSERT query:

  ```
  query.prepare("INSERT INTO films VALUES (1, convert_from(?,'UTF-8')))");
  ```

This should also work for other encodings, `UTF-8` above is an example.

---

About the difference between Windows/Ubuntu: it's not clear why QtSql would behave differently, but maybe it's a difference in postgres configuration.

`'\x417661746172'` is the text representation of `Avatar` in UTF-8 as a binary string but only when `bytea_output` is set to `hex`. If `bytea_output` is set to `escape`, that would be exactly `Avatar` and indiscernible from the text itself.

Example in the psql command-line client:

```
test=> set bytea_output=hex;
SET
test=> select 'Avatar'::bytea;
     bytea      
----------------
 \x417661746172
(1 row)

test=> set bytea_output=escape;
SET
test=> select 'Avatar'::bytea;
 bytea  
--------
 Avatar
(1 row)
```

That escaping of `bytea` also happens on the client side within drivers such as `QPSQL`, and the `hex` flavor in only available since PostgreSQL 9.0. Before that, `escape` was the only method and the `bytea_output` parameter didn't exist.
I believe that simply having QtSql linked with a libpq older than `9.0` on the Windows machine might explain why you get the 'text-like' appareance versus the 'hex-like' appearance on a recent Ubuntu.

Comment: The `convert_from` is helpful to know, thanks. It's interesting that on Windows the `QtSql` layer is automatically doing conversion of the bytes (presumably to `UTF-8`), whereas on Ubuntu it must be done explicitly.

Comment: @Lozzer: I've added a possible explanation about that in the answer. I believe it's not really  windows vs ubuntu but rather a version/config difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `bindValue` instead of `addBindValue`. Refer this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare).

Comment: Same result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem wit Qt 5.6 on Windows and PostgresSQL 9.6 on debian.
When compiling with 64-bit the bytea is readed as binary.
When compiling with 32-bit the bytea is readed as hex.

```
CREATE TABLE image (
   id serial,
   name text,
   picture bytea
 );

sql_query.prepare("SELECT id, name, picture FROM image");
...
QByteArray name = sql_query.value("name").toByteArray();
QByteArray Picture = SQL_query.value("Picture").toByteArray();

varchar read with both (32-bit and 64-bit) into QByteArray as string.

//Output 64-Bit application:
name = "Test", Picture = "‰PNG\r\n\x1a\n\0\0..."
//Output 32-Bit application:
Name = "Test", Picture = "x89504e470d0a1a0a0000..."
```

I added after open following query, and it works now

```
  QSqlQuery sql_query;
  sql_query.exec("SET bytea_output = 'escape'");
```

Both postgres Drivers are from pg 9.5, the 64-bit is from installed Postgres, the 32-bit was downloaded within a zip file. Both have same Name "libpq.dll"